# How can I use CastCompanionLibrary for Android to show live Youtube or Vimeo video?

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, vimeo, vimeo-android

I have succeeded to cast buffered mp4 video (e.g. url like http://a.com/1.mp4) to my TV  with the CastCompanionLibrary.

But I get "mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null" in the debug log when I try to cast a youtube video to the TV. I guess it would be same problem for Vimeo's video stream too.

How can I do that? Can it be that my MediaInfo is wrong? Do you have any example for a MediaInfo object for the live video? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use CCL to play YT videos; for CCL to cast a media, you need to provide the url to that media and you don't have such urls for YT content. The only solution to cast YT content is to use YT's embedded player on your receiver.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali for the quick answer! So it would be same to cast Vimeo streaming video right? I also need to have Vimeo's embedded play on my receiver. I need to cast both Youtube video and Vimeo video on the TV. Is there any instruction or example on making such advanced receiver? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how vimeo works so cannot comment on that. For YT, you can still use CCL on your android sender as long as you understand what aspects of it is going to be useful for you: CCL can manage connectivity and launch of your app; it can also provide a custom data channel for you. You'd need to write your own custom receiver and then use the custom channel to send commands to your receiver, such as "play this content with this ID" or "pause". In the custom receiver, you include a YT iframe player and then interpret the messages and call the appropriate commands on the YT player.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Vimeo also has iframe player. So I guess that it could be done in the same way as the Youtube player. Then I just hope that there is a way to send a parameter so that the receiver can know if it should show a YT player or Vimeo player. I will try it. Many thanks to you for answering my question on a weekend!

Answer (score 3):

Vimeo provides PRO users with MP4 links to their *own* videos. You could use the CCL to cast these videos by constructing a MediaInfo object with their respective MP4 file links and content type. See [Video File](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/dev/vimeo-networking/src/main/java/com/vimeo/networking/model/VideoFile.java) in the Vimeo Java/Android networking library for more info on what you would use to construct the MediaInfo objects.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your advice! I will try that.

Comment: This is a very good solution for playing Vimeo video. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Whats the url mp4 which accepts chromecast?

```
  "quality": "hd",
  "quality": "mobile",
  "quality": "sd",
  "quality": "hls",
```

I have been trying with all on my LGWEB OS but there was a problem with the file type and audio codecs.

edit:On apple TV its working then the problem is the web os.